# Audio email client

Tags: email-client, screen-reader

I am voluntarily supporting visually impaired computer users. I have explored screen reader applications but am looking for an alternative way for the users to access email.

Is there an application that has a dedicated audio interface for receiving and sending email? An audio email client.

Phrasing a search for suitable software has proved difficult as 'embedding audio in email' or 'dictating bulk email' feature in the search results.

Ideally it would run on any OS. My clients all speak English as their first language.

Comment: a) For which operating system(s)? b) The client should read out both, the interface/menus as well as the email content, correct? c) For which language(s)?

Comment: Ideally it would run on any OS. My clients all speak English as their first language.

Comment: In a truly audio only interface the traditional drop-down menu concept would not apply.
Instead it would likely be a list of option, similar to a automated phone system I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at [python](http://python.org), (which has email client libraries in the default set plus plenty of others available), plus the google API based [speech recognition](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/2.1.3) & [text to speech](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google_speech/) libraries.

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform
- Multiple language support

You could also look at making it a feature request & *possibly contributing some effort or at least testing* on [MailPile](https://www.mailpile.is/)!